# import variables into stylus and scss

Tags: css, sass, stylus

I use stylus and scss in my project.
Is it possible to have one common variables file that I can use with both?

I have tried:

variables.scss

```
$primary: #00A9E0
```

main.styl

```
@import 'variables.scss"
```

which obviously did not work because of the different syntax

Answer (score -1):

Move your variables to `_variables.scss`(partial file) and import it.
`@import 'variables';`

Comment: I dont think this works because stylus and sass use a different syntax for variables $primary: ... vs $primary = ...